# installing rails unable to download data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to install rails on a new computer and am running to the following command issue:

```
gem install rails
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from http://gems.rubyforge.org/ -SSL_connect reuterned=1 error=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: Unknown protocol (http://gems.rubyforge.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

Comment: why are you installing from rubyforge and not from rubygems...?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the latest rvm than you can update your certificates and rubygems. Or just use the non-ssl source.

Comment: I did but Nothing change what can i do